# How to run javafx applications in intellij idea IDE

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, javafx

I am trying to run JavaFX application but there is showing the following error

Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

Until this step, I could not import the JavaFX, and I have done it from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

Can someone help to solve this error?

Thanks beforehand.
By the way, I am using lubuntu operating system

extra information
[image]

Comment: Take a look the sample project here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-overview.htm#BABGBBDH

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53668630/how-to-run-javafx-applications-in-intellij-idea-ide

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As explained on [official OpenJFX website](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij)

- open your intellij idea IDE and create new Project
- Go to **File > Project Structure**
- Go to **Project Settings > Libraries**
- Click on **+** button
- Locate **..\openjfx-11.0.1_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-11.0.1\lib** folder from extracted zip of openJFX 11
- Apply settings and click **ok**
- Go to **File > Settings**
- In Settings go to **Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Path Variables**
- Click on **+** and add new path variable name it **PATH_TO_FX** and in value field locate  **..\openjfx-11.0.1_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-11.0.1\lib** folder
- Apply settings and click **ok**
- The go to **Run > Edit Configurations**
- Select your Application from **Application > {your application name}**
- Then click on **Configuration** tab and in **VM options** field write this:
  **--module-path ${PATH_TO_FX} --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml**
- Then Click on
  [Edit templates button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjxWS.png) select Application in Templates and again in **VM options** field write this:
  **--module-path ${PATH_TO_FX} --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml**
- Apply settings and click **ok** and now you are good to go
- You have to do this whenever you create new project in intellij

Comment: Thanks, I looked through official OpenJFX docs and I downloaded open-jdk and open-jfx and I showed the path for sdk and jdk. Then Finally, I could make that work
Thank you very much
I appreciate your time.

Comment: Excellent and useful reply. I would also suggest to go to the Edit Configurations and tick "Store as project file" box and put the created XML config file under VCS.

Comment: This is really helpful!!!!! I was doing the same process over and over, but that template was the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There is no strictly defined javafx in openjdk8.

You need to install **openjfx** via commandline:

```
sudo apt-get install openjfx
```

Comment: I have installed it, should I configure it as well, if yes how can I do it

Comment: You need to add file:
/usr/lib/jvm/<your open-jdk>/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar

Comment: Sorry if I am asking a weird question how can I add it
Do I need to add it project structure/ dependencies tab?

Comment: File -> Project Structure -> Libraries -> '+'