# Cannot get JavaFX jar file to open

Tags: java, javafx

I...for the life of me, cannot get a javaFX jar to run. I am taking a Java class and doing a project that involves having an app I created play a game against another student's app with the professor's app as the arbiter managing things. I am using Win10, Java 14.02 and I have JavaFX 15.0.1.

I added the GhostApp (professor's app), my app, and other relative files into the same central folder and used CMD to cd to that directory.

I ran the set PATH_TO_FX command to my JAVAFX lib folder, and then I ran the following command.

```
java --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules javafx.controls
```

No matter if I do it by relative path or absolute path for both of the jar files, CMD always yields the following error:

```
F:\empty_ghost_project>java --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules javafx.controls GhostApp.jar the_great_decider.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class GhostApp.jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: GhostApp.jar
```

I did also confirm using "dir" that the files are indeed actually in that folder just as a sanity check.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong and I been working on this since yesterday.   I believe I have the project completed but it is really difficult to test it manually with Intellij.  I have already emailed my professor but I am looking for outside in the mean-time.

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: F:\empty_ghost_project\GhostApp.jar that's a file, not a class. If you are using command line to run the app you are donig something wrong with your command.
Kindly format any code or command run as code.

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari, I agree that ghostapp.jar is a file and not a class, I am pasting the error from the command line.  I will edit my OP to make that clearer.

Comment: Refer to the documentation. [The java Command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/java.html). Note the `-jar` option.

Comment: Does the answer here help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53668630/how-to-run-javafx-applications-in-intellij-idea-ide